# How do I autoscan local documents to add words to a custom dictionary?

Tags: macos, unix, dictionary, scripting

I'd like my dictionary to know more of the words I use - and don't want to manually add all possible words as I end up typing them (I'm a biologist/bioinformatician - there's lots of jargon and specific software and species names). Instead I want to:

1. Take a directory of existing documents. These are PDFs or Word/latex documents of scientific articles; I guess they could be "easily" be converted to plain text.
2. **Pull out all words that are not in the "normal" dictionary.**
3. Add these to my local custom dictionary (on my mac that's  `~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`. But it would make sense to add them in the libreoffice/word/ispell custom dictionaries as well.

1 and 3 are easy. How can I do 2? Thanks!

Comment: comments/suggestions to justify the downvote?

Comment: if you have a word list why not just  import the wordlist? the application which you are using will take of merging extra words.

Comment: What do you define as a "normal" dictionary? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. The mac or ispell have builtin dictionaries for the english language. My PDFs are in english- but they also include some extra domains-specific jargon. If I write a text, each domain-specific word is underlined and I can manually add it to the dictionary. I'd like to automate this based on a directory of "trusted" pdfs where I am certain that there are no spelling mistakes...  I simply want to add words that are not yet in the internal dictionary to a custom dictionary...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to remove duplicates (that already exist in the system dictionary). You might want to ask first, if this is really necessary, though. I guess they won't cause any problems and won't increase word-spell-checking excessively, so there is no real reason for **step 2** in my opinion.

I think you'll have a much harder time with **step 1**. Extracting plain-text from a PDF may sound easy, but it certainly is not. You'll end up with plenty of unknown symbols. You need to fix split-words at the end of a line and you probably want to exclude equations/links/numbers/etc. before adding all these to your dictionary.

But if you have some tool to get this done and can create a couple of **.txt** files really containing only the words/sentences you need, then I would go with something like the following python code to "solve" the merge **for your local dictionary only**. Of course you can also extend this to load the system dictionary (wherever that is?) and merge it the same way I show below.

*Please note that I left out any error handling on purpose.*

Save as `import_to_dict.py`, adjust the paths to your requirements and call with `python import_to_dict.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os,re

# 1 - load existing dictionaries from files (adjust paths here!)
dictionary_file = '~/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary'
global_dictionary_file = '/Library/Spelling/GlobalDictionary'
txt_file_folder = '~/Documents/ConvertedPapers'

reg_exp = r'[\s,.|/]+' #add symbols here

with open(local_dictionary_file, 'r') as f:
    # splitting with regular expressions shouldn't really be needed for the dictionary, but it should work
    dictionary = set(re.split(reg_exp,f.read()))

with open(global_dictionary_file, 'r') as f:
    # splitting with regular expressions shouldn't really be needed for the dictionary, but it should work
    global_dictionary = set(re.split(reg_exp,f.read()))

# 2 - walk over all sub-dirs in your folder
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(txt_file_folder):
    # open all files (this could easily be limited to only .txt files)
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as txt_f:
            # read the file contents
            words = txt_f.read()
            # split into word-set (set guarantees no duplicates)
            word_set = set(re.split(reg_exp,words))
            # remove any already in dictionary existing words
            missing_words = (word_set - dictionary) - global_dictionary
            # add missing words to dictionary
            dictionary |= missing_words

# 3 - write dictionary file
with open(dictionary_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(dictionary))
```

Comment: thanks - can you add to this how to remove words that already exist in the system dictionary?

Comment: As I tried to say - I don't believe this is necessary - why do you think you need this? Duplicate words won't be a problem - I can add some code, but you would have to know what format / file the global dictionary is in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic java program that will generate a text file containing all of the unique words in a directory of plain text files, separated by a newline.

You can just replace the input directory and output file path strings with correct values for your system and run it.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MakeDictionary {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Hashtable<String, Boolean> dictionary = new Hashtable<String, Boolean>();

        String inputDir = "C:\\test";
        String outputFile = "C:\\out\\dictionary.txt";


        File[] files = new File(inputDir).listFiles();

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                BufferedReader in = null;
                try {
                    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getCanonicalPath()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] words = line.split(" ");
                        for (String word : words) {
                            dictionary.put(word, true);
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        in.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Set<String> wordset = dictionary.keySet();
        Iterator<String> iter = wordset.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            out.write(iter.next());
            out.newLine();
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```